# Hiding bad (closed/downvoted questions) on front page?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm concerned by the fact that the main page of Theoretical Computer Science is usually filled with many (around 50%) "bad" questions, i.e., questions that have received many downvotes or have even been closed.

I understand the need to show new questions to the community and not bury them instantaneously, but I'm concerned it's making the site look bad to a newcomer, and it is personally inconvenient for me.

So I have three variants of the same question:

- **Is there a way for "the community" to hide bad questions from the front page? (Let's say the ones that are closed or have score <= -3 or something.)**
- **Is there a link I can give to the site which would hide these questions (to make it more appealing to a newcomer)?**
- **Can I, personally, configure my profile to hide these bad questions from my view of the front page?**

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way for "the community" to hide bad questions from the front page? (Let's say the ones that are closed or have score <= -3 or something.

That happens already, but the threshold is [-4 or lower](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62769/295232). You can still view those questions via other question lists, e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions

> Is there a link I can give to the site which would hide these questions (to make it more appealing to a newcomer)?

Not sure if it's a good link to share, but [this search query](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20score%3a0) lists the newest questions with a score of 0 or higher. See the Help Center article [How do I search?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/searching) for more options.

> Can I, personally, configure my profile to hide these bad questions from my view of the front page?

No. You can ignore certain *tags* but not questions under a certain score.

Comment: OK thanks! Indeed the search result link isn't a great URL to share. So yeah it doesn't look like there is a good solution to the problem... but many thanks for listing these options!

Comment: The -4 threshold is adequate for large sites such as SO, but on a small site like here, a higher number (say, -2) would perhaps works better. But I don’t know if this would have any chance as a feature request.